# CMake does not find CxxTest package

Tags: cmake, cxxtest

I wrote the following `CMakeLists.txt` in order to build a tester using **CxxTest** (it's almost the standard example provided by `FindCxxTest`):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(tester)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
find_package(CxxTest REQUIRED)
if(CXXTEST_FOUND)
    include_directories(${CXXTEST_INCLUDE_DIR})
    enable_testing()
    CXXTEST_ADD_TEST(tester_executable runner.cpp
                        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/myTestsuite.h)
endif()
```

The problem is that **CxxTest** is not found although I have the folder cxxtest and the file `cxxtest/TestSuite.h` inside the directory where `CMakeLists.txt` exists.

I already looked into the source code of `FindCxxTest.cmake` to see how far it gets, but it doesn't even find the path `CXXTEST_INCLUDE_DIR`.

Do I have to set another search path or something? I'm testing on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_path` does not search the current list directory. That is, just because a relative path is reachable from the current CMakeLists.txt, does not mean that it will be found. You can find a complete description of the search order in [the manual](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/find_path.html).

A quick and dirty solution is to add the respective directory to your [`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html):

```
 set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
 find_package(CxxTest)
```

More fine grained control is available via the `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`, `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH`, `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` and `CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH` variables. Also, some find scripts provide means of injecting search hints without having to pollute the global variables (although `FindCxxTest` does not seem to offer this).

Another option is, if you anyway include the CxxTest sources at a fixed place in your source tree, to not use the the find script at all, but hardcode the paths instead.

This may feel like a dirty solution at first, but if you can really rely on the sources always being there, it's actually the cleanest and most robust way to solve this. Find scripts really only make sense when you can *not* say where exactly on the system the files are located.

Comment: I tried your quick and dirty solution but it does not work. In the example of my question I also set the variable `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` but that did not help either.

Comment: @cwde Double-check your paths. The find script uses `find_path(CXXTEST_INCLUDE_DIR cxxtest/TestSuite.h)`, which will work if `${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/cxxtest/TestSuite.h` is found. Note that this will only set the `CXXTEST_INCLUDE_DIR` variable and nothing else. In particular, `CXXTEST_FOUND` will likely still be false afterwards. Apply similar fixes for the missing components until the complete find script passes.